# ngx-intl-tel-input can't able to give custom tabindex

Tags: html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

> I have used ngx-intl-tel-input as a separate component and tried to
> give custom tabindex but it's not taking to country box field and
> input box field actually how can i make it possible?

`<ngx-intl-tel-input *ngIf="!tooltip && type == 'phone' && !showPasswordIcon" [inputId]="fcn ? fcn : 'mobileNumber'" cssClass="form-control input-md" class="phone-box" [enablePlaceholder]="enablePlaceholder" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Australia" [maxLength]="15" [separateDialCode]="true" [formControl]="form.controls[fcn]" [phoneValidation]="true" container="body" (paste)="onlyNumbers($event)" (drop)="onlyNumbers($event)" triggers="manual" #inputContainer customPlaceholder="Mobile number"> </ngx-intl-tel-input>`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider creating a directive that can help you to add `tabIndex` on desired input element.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[addTabIndex]',
})
export class AddTabIndexDirective {
  @Input() addTabIndex;
  @Input() targetElement = 'input';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const input = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(this.targetElement);
    if (input && this.addTabIndex) {
      this.render.setAttribute(input, 'tabindex', this.addTabIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input addTabIndex="2"><ngx-intl-tel-input/>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-tel-input-kvkcqe)

Comment: i have tried both but still not able to acess the input through tab key in ngx-intl-tel-input

Comment: @AthitthiyanAnand may I know what is not working. Did you see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-tel-input-kvkcqe)?

Comment: @AthitthiyanAnand long time no see, any luck on the above?

Comment: it's not working in my case but working separately i have seen that stackblitz no use still trying to figureout what gone wrong there

Comment: Can you please try replicating the issue in stackblitz? And share forked plunker